# Code sharing between spark workers

Tags: scala, apache-spark

According to Spark documentation it is better to use anonymous or scala object functions in RDD transformations. I have object with next code:

```
object Util {
  val someManager = new Manager()

  def process(data: String) = someManager.manage(data)
}
```

And I call it next way:

```
myRDD.map(Util.process)
```

How Util object will be serialized and sent to spark workers? Does manager will be created for sending every time or only once? How much times instance of manager will be sent to spark workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How Util object will be serialized and sent to spark workers? Does
>   manager will be created for sending every time or only once? How much
>   times instance of manager will be sent to spark workers?

`Util.process` is wrapped inside an `AbstractFunction1` at compile time which implements it's `apply` method, which is what gets serialized. You can see this when you decompile this code (this is reconstructed from JVM byte code):

```
par.map(new AbstractFunction1() {
  public static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

  public final void apply(String data)
  {
    Util..MODULE$.process(data);
  }
 }, ClassTag..MODULE$.Unit());
}
```

Another thing we want to see is how the `Util` object get's compiled into byte code:

```
public final class Util$
{
  public static final  MODULE$;
  private final Manager someManager;

  public Manager someManager()
  {
    return this.someManager;
  }

  private Util$()
  {
    MODULE$ = this;
    this.someManager = new Manager();
  }

  public void process(String data)
  {
    someManager().manage(data);
  }
}
```

This means that we still have an instance field for `Manager`. What will happen is that Spark will use it's [`ClosureCleaner`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/ClosureCleaner.scala) to clean out the instance of `Util`, since it doesn't need it, but it will use need to serialize the `Manager` instance to the workers, and it will do it *every time* it needs to invoke `map`. This doesn't mean that there will be multiple instances of `Manager`, it simply means that the single instance will need to be serialized and sent over the wire. We can see the details in the documentation of `ClosureCleaner`:

> - The mechanism is to traverse the hierarchy of enclosing closures and **null out any references along the way that are not actually used
>     by the starting closure, but are nevertheless included in the
>     compiled anonymous classes.** Note that it is unsafe to simply
>     mutate the enclosing closures in place, as other code paths may depend
>     on them. Instead, we clone each enclosing closure and set the
>     parent pointers accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Util needs to be serializable otherwise you will get an exception. Manager will be send every time eg with every task. You can send it only once per partition though, for this you need to broadcast it first, see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

Comment: Please explain the downvote, for me this answers the three questions asked.

Comment: I not the one who voted but this doesn't sound right: __Util needs to be serializable__.

Comment: If Manager is not serializable then Util wont be serializable and Spark wont be able to take the closure in the map.

Comment: There is no need to serialize here. `objects` are singletons.

Comment: The class of the object is still serialized and sent to the executor right? You are right though it just has to be compiled and has nothing to do with extending serializable.